# Image coerces (table) plot labels to continuous

Tags: r, r-factor

Using `data(warpbreaks)` since it's a dataset with `factor`s which everyone has:

```
tapply(warpbreaks[,1], warpbreaks[,2:3], FUN=sum)
#    tension
#wool   L   M   H
#   A 401 216 221
#   B 254 259 169

require(magrittr)
tapply(warpbreaks[,1], warpbreaks[,2:3], FUN=sum) %>% image
```

[image: image(table(warpbreaks))]

As you can see, the labels (which *were* factors) have now been coerced to continuous.

---

(And some obvious twiddles like `image(ylab=levels( warpbreaks$tension ))` aren't the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You've created a matrix in which the factor levels of `wool` and `tension` are now just row and column names of the matrix you're feeding to `image`. Are you looking for a heatmap? For example:

```
heatmap(tapply(warpbreaks[,1], warpbreaks[,2:3], FUN=sum))
```

[image]

Comment: Basically, although I don't need the dendrogram (and would actually like a legend, like `fields::image.plot`). `?heatmap` says it's basically `image(t(x))`. Weird…

Comment: Also, if you don't want the row or column dendrograms, then just add `Rowv=NA` and/or `Colv=NA` to the call to `heatmap`.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out from the source what `heatmap` does that `image` doesn't…looks like these 2 lines: ```image(1L:nc, 1L:nr, x, xlim = 0.5 + c(0, nc), ylim = 0.5 + 
        c(0, nr), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", ...);

    axis(1, 1L:nc, labels = labCol, las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0, 
        cex.axis = cexCol)```,

emphasis on `axes=FALSE`.